# pry shell breaks with long output

Tags: ruby, pry

I just installed pry. With the "pry" command it seems to start up fine. I can issue basic commands, no problem. However if I issue a command whose output is long, I am unable to issue further commands. For example, if I issue the help command I get the following:

```
[1] pry(main)> help
Help
  help               Show a list of commands or information about a specific command.
...
...
...
Prompts
  simple-prompt      Toggle the simple prompt.
(END)
```

I can page down to the end of the help listing and "(END)" is displayed. However I cannot get back to the REPL (ctrl-C doesn't work). Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try pressing `q`?

Comment: I tried various things, but not that, and indeed it works. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `q` to return to command mode.

Comment: Is there a way of always going to command mode by default on long results? @zwippie

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable this feature using the command `pry_instance.config.pager = false` or with a config file

See https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_pager